# Flink map tuple to string

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Hi  I have some tuple `Tuple2<String, Integer>` that i want to convert to string an then send it to KAFKA.

Im trying to figure out a way to to iterate the tuple and create  one string from it so if i have N elements in my tuple i want to create a string that contain them.

I tried flat map it   but im geting new string for each element in the tuple.

```
  SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> s = t.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, String>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(Tuple2<String, Integer> stringIntegerTuple2, Collector<String> collector) throws Exception {

            collector.collect(stringIntegerTuple2.f0 + stringIntegerTuple2.f1);
            }
        });
```

What is the correct way to create on string out of tuple .

Comment: So to make sure I understand your goal properly, let's say you have, for example, Tuple3<String, String, String> myTupleObject. And lets say the string values are red, green, and blue. You're ideal goal is to say "String myKafkaString = convertTupleToString(myTupleObject)" and have "red, green, blue" be the value of myKafkaString, right? The reason I am asking, besides just making sure I understand properly, is that I am wondering why you don't just serialize the tuple and send it to kafka.

Comment: the main reason that i want to send the message to influx db via kafka  therefore i need to send the data as  influx line protocol 
the ideal result of the mapping will be somthing like that.
" measurement color=red,color=green,color=blue  "

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the `.toString()` method of a tuple with a custom class and use that. Like this:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3;

public class CustomTuple3 extends Tuple3 {

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "measurment color=" + this.f0.toString() + " color=" + this.f1.toString() + " color=" + this.f2.toString();
    }
}
```

So now just use a CustomTuple3 object instead of a Tuple3 and when you populate it and call `.toString()` on it, it will output that formatted string.